# Lowest and highest value in an interval of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

can someone help with this problem?
I have the function:

$F(x,y,z)= x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

And I need to find its lowest and highest value in the interval:

$x+2y+3z \le 1$

$x\ge 0, y\ge 0, z\ge 0$

It's not hard to find that it has a local minimum at $(0,0,0)$ by using derivatives and the Hessian matrix, but what about the maximum? How would I find that?

Comment: You don't have to use Hessian. It's a problem on a closed set. All you have to do, is check the points for which $F_x=0, F_y=0, F_z=0$, and the borders, so when $x+2y+3z=1, x=0, y=0, z=0$. This set even has it's name. It's called Simplex.

Comment: The constraints define a tetahedron with vertexes at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0),(0,\frac 12, 0), (0,0,\frac 13)$  one of those will maximize the objective function.

Comment: How can, if $x+2y+3z = 1$ then $x=y=z=0$, @Adam ?

Comment: @amWhy, I meant all of those as different cases. I know i used comma as "and" for the partial derivatives, so i probably shouldn't use comma for those too

Comment: That makes more sense, @Adam.  So we get, as an example, when $x=1, and $y=0,$ and $z=0$, we get $x+2y +3z = 1+2(0) + 3(z) = 1$

Comment: How would one go about proving that a maximum isn't reached somewhere inside the tetrahedron? @Doug M

Comment: If you had a different function, you would need to investigate that.  But with what you have, it is the your function returns the distance of $(x,y,z)$ from the origin, you might also note that $\nabla F = (2x,2y,2z) \ne (0,0,0)$ anywhere but the origin.